# Android Studio Android Phone "Android Version" 9.0 with SDK API v22?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-min-sdk

I'm a new Android developer using Android Studio.  I've purchased a phone to test my app.  My app runs SDK API 27 and higher (i.e., OS Oreo 8+).

**My specific question is** why does my Android version 9.0 phone have SDK API of 22 rather than SDK API 28?

I purchased a phone that says its running Android 9.0 (Settings->About Phone->Android version = 9.0)

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) and other links Android 9 should have SDK APIs of 28.

When I connect the device to Android Studio with USB Developer Mode enabled, I get a red (!) error that Android 9T (minds(API 27) > deviceSdk(API 22))[image: Android Studio Image]

Additionally, I cannot download my app from Google Play as google play also thinks the API level is too low.

Another interesting thing about the phone is that it won't let me upgrade to Android 10, which I thought it should be able to.  When I click the Android 9.0, nothing happens, i.e. 10.0 isn't available.

Comment: In my opinion, everything is pointing to one thing. you have been scammed and the android on the phone is not an actually 9 and that's fake. what is the phone model?

Comment: Thanks @MehranB  I'm thinking the same thing.  The Model number (also under Settings...) says "9T".  This phone version also doesn't seem to exist.  Although it looks a lot like Xiaomi Mi 9T, but doesn't say its Xiaomi Mi 9T, just "9T"

Comment: sorry to hear that man. it sucks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry! Because of my reputation, I can't comment. As [@Mehran B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10695663/mehran-b) said you may be scammed. First, find IMEI Number of your mobile from the settings. Then go to [here](https://www.imei.info/)
. Type your IMEI Number there and check info like Company Name, Model that matches with your physical device.

Hope helpful!

Comment: I'm able to find the IMEI and it says the phone is a Techno F3 from June 2018 on Nougat.  When I look up the Techno F3 the pictures don't look like my phone.  The Techno F3 should have Nougat (SDK API 24/25).

Comment: @Jacksonsox Then it is not a real model. Sorry to say this you have been scammed by the seller.